# String Returns mutiple line but when saving to text file only last line gets saved

Tags: java

I try to read pdf file which contains multiple lines like below, based on the existence of text, i try to fetch the line and want to store into a text file. When i am reading the PDF file and printing it, i could see complete output but when saving only last line gets saved.

Sample Content on the pdf file

---

Color Combination......Deep Red

Side Colour Combo.....slight yellow

---

When i am doing System.out.println();

i am able to see both the lines

But when i am saving the output into text file, i could see only

Side Colour Combo.....slight yellow

Below is my code : I need both the lines into the text file, i am not sure how to make that happen.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PrintingOnlyLastLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        boolean ColorVal;
        String my_new_str_ColorVal;
        String[] lines;

        File root = new File("<pdf file folder list>");
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                f.getAbsolutePath();

            } else {
                File pdffile = new File("<pdf file folder list>" + f.getName());
                try {

                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdffile);
                    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                    String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);

                    lines = text.split("\\r?\\n", -1);
                    for (String line : lines) {

                        ColorVal = line.contains("Color");
                        my_new_str_ColorVal = line.replace(".", "");

                        if (ColorVal) {
                            try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(
                                    "Output.txt"))) {
                                out.print(my_new_str_ColorVal);
                                System.out.println(my_new_str_ColorVal);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } // else statement ending

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: which `FileOutputStream` constructor are you using, and what gives you the impression that it will append to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileOutputStream truncates your file. Therefore you cannot iterate over your lines in your for-loop and append them one by one.

To fix this, you could either join your lines into a single string before saving it to your file or you could keep your code as it currently is and instead use the an overload of the FileOutputStream constructor, which accepts the append option:

FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)

```
try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Output.txt"), true)) {
    out.print(my_new_str_ColorVal);
    System.out.println(my_new_str_ColorVal);
}
```

Setting append to true will keep previous file contents.

You can find a list of the supported constructor overloads in the docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

## Edit:

I do not know why it's not working for you. I've tested my first solution idea and it works for me. Anyways, I have quickly implemented the initial solution which only requires opening the file once by creating a single String. Therefore we do not need the overloaded constructor anymore. This does work for me:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.Loader;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class PrintingOnlyLastLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean ColorVal;
        String my_new_str_ColorVal;
        String[] lines;

        File root = new File("src");
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                f.getAbsolutePath();

            } else {
                File pdffile = new File("src\\" + f.getName());
                try {

                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                    PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(pdffile);
                    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                    String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);

                    lines = text.split("\\r?\\n", -1);
                    String output = "";
                    for (String line : lines) {

                        ColorVal = line.contains("Color");
                        my_new_str_ColorVal = line.replace(".", "");

                        if (ColorVal) {
                            output = output.concat(my_new_str_ColorVal).concat("\n");
                        }
                    }
                    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Output.txt"))) {
                        out.print(output);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } // else statement ending

        }

    }
}
```

Please note that I have used a different version of pdfbox. You might have to replace `Loader.loadPDF(pdffile);` with `PDDocument.load(pdffile);`

Also, please make sure that you have no typos in your input pdf file. For example "colour" instead of "color".

Comment: But they don't want to append if the file exists to begin with. A better solution is to open the file once outside the loop and close it after the loop.

Comment: @h.syd :    I tried as per your Suggestion, the output is still the same. I could see only one line.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to join the string outside the for loop and it worked. @tgdavies thanks for the hint.

@H.Syd, I have tried your option as well and it worked. My final code is as below:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PrintingOnlyLastLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean ColorVal;
        String my_new_str_ColorVal="";
        String my_new_str_ColorVal_Append="";
        String[] lines;
        
        File root = new File("/Users/nagappan/eclipse-workspace/PDFExtractor/PDFFiles/");
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                f.getAbsolutePath();
            } else {
                File pdffile = new File("/Users/nagappan/eclipse-workspace/PDFExtractor/PDFFiles/" + f.getName());
                try {
                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdffile);
                    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                    String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);

                    lines = text.split("\\r?\\n", -1);
                    for (String line : lines) {

                        ColorVal = line.contains("Color");
                        my_new_str_ColorVal = line.replace(".", "");
                        
                        if (ColorVal) {
                            my_new_str_ColorVal_Append=my_new_str_ColorVal_Append+my_new_str_ColorVal;
                        }
                    }//end of for loop
                    System.out.println(my_new_str_ColorVal_Append); //this needs to be written inside the file
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // else statement ending
        }
    }
}
```